# Can I map domain to another subdomain?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have xx.test-domain.com and I need to map domain xx.real-domain.com to the first domain, is there any option what can I do here?

Is there any DNS setting, that allows me to map one subdomain on second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CNAME` record to do that.

```
xx.real-domain.com CNAME xx.test-domain.com
```

It will make `xx.real-domain.com` an alias of `xx.test-domain.com`.